# Principal Component Analysis direction

Tags: signal-processing, pca

PCA divides the signal in individual orthogonal components, such as the first component contains the dimension with greatest variance and so on.

As I see it the direction of the component is random, as the variance has the same magnitude independent if it is directed upwards or downwards. For a single signal this may not matter, but if You compare for example many individuals with PCA's of biological signals (for example with 12-lead Electrocardiograms) it may matter if the amplitude of PC1 is negative or positive. Which methods exist to make a intelligent way of direction of the Principal components?